# Is it possible to disable Speech Reference Card?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

Microsoft Speech Recognition comes with a Speech Reference Card. It consists in some pre-determined words that are recognized.

I want to know if it's possible to disable it. Is it?

EDIT:
I want to remove all pre-defined commands.
This ones:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Common-commands-in-Speech-Recognition

EDIT2:
I'm using SpeechLib!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  Do you mean that you want to disable the pre-defined commands?  Or just the command that brings up the speech reference card?

Comment: I want to remove all pre-defined commands!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to change the code to use what you said, I've discovered what I needed!

With this command:

```
recGrammar.SetGrammarState(SPGRAMMARSTATE.SPGS_EXCLUSIVE);
```

all worked!

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717258%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an in-process recognizer, instead of a shared recognizer.

Since you're using C#, you need to use the [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) class if you're using System.Speech.Recognition.

In particular, you need to also set the Audio Input property of the recognizer using [SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtodefaultaudiodevice(v=VS.100).aspx), so that the inproc recognizer knows where to get the audio from.